# Terraform formatlist interpolation with embedded functions and their execution order

Tags: terraform

I have this:

`formatlist( "cidrhost( cidrsubnet(%s, 1, 0), -3)", list("10.70.32.0/21"))`

output:

```
[
  "cidrhost( cidrsubnet(10.70.32.0/21, 1, 0), -3)",
]
```

but i'd like that executed and the result being stored in the `formatlist` return list. Can i get Terraform to defer executing the `cidr` functions until after the formatlist `%s` has been subsitited with the list item ?

At the moment if i remove the quotes and try it just fails e.g.

```
formatlist( cidrhost( cidrsubnet("%s", 1, 0), -3), list("10.70.32.0/21"))

  cidrsubnet: invalid CIDR expression: invalid CIDR address: %s in:

${formatlist( cidrhost( cidrsubnet("%s", 1, 0), -3), list("10.70.32.0/21"))}
```

Which leads me to believe that `cidrsubnet` is running before `formatlist` has a chance to do anything.

**Update with example:**

For example i have a long list of class-c subnets which we subnet in half and from the 1st subnet we use the 2nd last usable ( non broadcast ) address for a per subnet mgmt server.

e.g list ( actually much longer )

```
10.70.30.0/24
10.70.31.0/24
10.70.32.0/24
```

`cidrsubnet("10.70.30.0/24", 1, 0)` will split in two and return the 1st subnet i.e. `10.70.30.0/25`. Then `cidrhost(10.70.30.0/25, -3)` will give me the 3rd from last address i.e. `10.70.30.124`.

So the output from the above list i want is:

```
10.70.30.124/25
10.70.31.124/25
10.70.32.124/25
```

Given the lack of iteration in Terraform i wanted to incorporate the above logic with `formatlist` to loop over the source list, do `cidr/subnet` magic and output the desired list.

Many thanks.

Comment: It's not overly clear what you're trying to achieve here. Could you post a list of inputs and expected outputs as well please?

Comment: ok sure, updated.. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```tf
variable "ipcidr" {
  default = "10.70.32.0/24"
}

output "new_ipcidr" {
  value = "${join("/", list(cidrhost(cidrsubnet(var.ipcidr, 1, 0), -4), element(split("/", cidrsubnet(var.ipcidr, 1, 0)), 1)))}"
}
```

```sh
$ terraform init && terraform apply
Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

new_ipcidr = 10.70.32.124/25
```

To make this work for a list, the output value should be fed into a resource using the `count` and `count.index` approach to loop. For example.

```tf
resource "aws_subnet" "main" {
  count      = "${length(var.ipcidrs)}"
  vpc_id     = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"
  cidr_block = "${join("/", list(cidrhost(cidrsubnet(var.ipcidrs[count.index], 1, 0), -4), element(split("/", cidrsubnet(var.ipcidrs[count.index], 1, 0)), 1)))}"
}
```